# Drawing hexagonal grid on Android

Tags: java, android, tiles, hexagonal-grid

I'm trying to draw a hexagon grid in my Android application. I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, so I'm looking for some frameworks/libraries or just some basic ideas about how should one do this. Do you have some ideas?

What I found so far:

- [Some math but not for Android](http://www.gdreflections.com/2011/02/hexagonal-grid-math.html)
- [Nice, but not for Java](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14948/Hexagonal-grid-for-games-and-other-projects-Part-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The math applies to any platform, of course. Since you asked for basic ideas on how to do this: **just use the code from the [first link](http://www.gdreflections.com/2011/02/hexagonal-grid-math.html) you provided**. The java code for implementing all the required formulas is present and could be used as-is. Then you have an excellent example of how to tie that class into your existing code. Use the source from the simple java test applet as a guide to help you integrate this into your code.